# Run script automatically

Tags: php, html, apache

I have a PHP code that send e-mails and I have a html page that contains a button to run the PHP script with `post` method. Is there a way to run this script without recourse to the html page every time i want to send the e-mails?

Comment: This has already been asked. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318361/timed-tasks-cron-like-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on Linux you can use cron.

Comment: I'm hosting my files in a hosting company server. I have only Cpanel.

Comment: You may need to upgrade your hosting account to one with access to SSH or a more feature-rich admin panel. Contact your company's customer service and ask them if they offer a package that will allow you to set up cron jobs. If they do not you might want to look into switching hosting companies.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you just call the php file or php function ?

Comment: Is there a way to call a PHP file without using a html webpage?